# Org mode: Open more than one level for a certain heading?

Tags: org-mode

Org mode: Open more than one level for a certain heading?

For example

```
* test...
* test2...
```

If i open test...
it should open all levels, but test2 should stay the same.

```
* test

** testa

*** testb

* test2..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press `TAB TAB` or use the `org-show-subtree` command.